# How to populate JDBC connection string details using properties file

Tags: java, oracle, properties-file

I have code that defines a JDBC connection string with driver name, host, schema, and other details. I want to genericize the process of creating this connection string by populating these values from a properties file.

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//location.tcs.com:1520/ndrc.retg/com";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", "scott");
props.setProperty("password", "Mylife");
```

But I'm not sure how to go about doing this ... can any one help me please.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Properties jdbc; 
 String url ;

 private static void loadProperties(String path)
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        java.io.InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
        try
        {
            props.load(in);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {

        }
        jdbc = props;
    }

 private void setProps() {
     url = jdbc.getProperty("CONNECTIONSTRING")
 }

 public static void main (String[] args) throws Throwable {
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(loadProperties(args[0]));
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting error at getClass() method. Cannot make static reference to a non static method. and getting error at getConnection too.

Comment: Also, above returns only the connection string. I want schema details and every thing should be readable from a property file.

Comment: I tried many ways.. :( But couldn't find a way to solve this :(.. pls help